# Facebook Developer - Creating/Managing new app from api

Tags: facebook

I wanted to create and manage Facebook apps from code, are there any api for this or I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) to manage your apps but not create one!

> App Tokens
>
> App access tokens are used to make requests to Facebook APIs on behalf
>   of an app rather than a user. This can be used to modify the
>   parameters of your app, create and manage test users, or read your
>   application's insights. App access tokens can also be used to publish
>   content to Facebook on behalf of a person who has granted an open
>   graph publishing permission to your application.